# If pref(L) is regular, does that imply L is also regular?

Tags: regular-language, dfa, nfa, automaton

I have this exercise for homework:

> Say we have a language L. we know that the language `pref(L)` (all the prefixes of `L`, including all the words in `L` itself) is a regular language. Does this imply that the language `L` is regular as well?

I took the NFA of `pref(L)` and divided it (via 2 epsilon transitions from `q0`) to 2 separate NFA's, as 1 defines `L` and the other defines `pref(L)\L`.

What I actually got is a NFA for `L`, which means it is regular.

I am not sure this is the way or if it legal. I'd be glad for another lead.

Thanks in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generic computer science, not practical programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily the case that if pref(L) is regular, then L is regular as well.

As an example, let Σ = {a} be a unary alphabet. I'm going to claim that if L is *any* infinite language over Σ, then pref(L) = Σ*. To see this, first note that pref(L) ⊆ Σ* because every pref(L) is a language over Σ. Now, consider any string in Σ*, which must have the form a<sup>n</sup>. If L is an infinite language over Σ, it must contain at least one string of the form a<sup>m</sup> where m ≥ n. Then a<sup>n</sup> would be a prefix of a<sup>m</sup>, so a<sup>n</sup> ∈ pref(L). This shows that Σ* ⊆ pref(L) and that pref(L) ⊆ Σ*, so in this case Σ* = pref(L).

Now, all we need to do is find a nonregular language over Σ = {a}. As an example, take the language { a<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> | n ∈ N } of all strings whose length is a power of two. It's possible to prove using either the Myhill-Nerode theorem or the pumping lemma that this language is not regular. However, by the above result, we know that pref(L) is a regular language.

Hope this helps!